# My app crash while try to adding onClick listener on folder

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, storage

I get **NullPointerException Error** and my app crash when I try to add onClick listener on folder in my code. I fetch all the data and I tried so many things but but I get error. I tried to add safe call(?) and non null(!!), I add condition but nothing work. I also give all the permissions:
Caused by:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

com.example.filemanager.Fragments.InternalFragment.findFile(InternalFragment.kt:78)
com.example.filemanager.Fragments.InternalFragment.displayFiles(InternalFragment.kt:91)
com.example.filemanager.Fragments.InternalFragment.access$displayFiles(InternalFragment.kt:22)
com.example.filemanager.Fragments.InternalFragment$runtimePermission$1.onPermissionsChecked(InternalFragment.kt:60)
```

**This is my code**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.filemanager.Adapter.FileAdapter
import com.example.filemanager.FileSelectedListener
import com.example.filemanager.R
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter
import com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsReport
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.multi.MultiplePermissionsListener
import java.io.File
import java.lang.Exception


class InternalFragment : Fragment(), FileSelectedListener {

    private lateinit var recycler: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var fileList: ArrayList<File>
    private lateinit var storage: File
    private lateinit var fileAdapter: FileAdapter
    private lateinit var data: String

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_internal, container, false)
        runtimePermission()
        recycler = view.findViewById(R.id.rvInternal)

        val internalStorage: String? = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
        storage = File(internalStorage.toString())

        try {
            data = arguments?.getString("path") ?: toString()
            val file: File = File(data)
            storage = file
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return view
    }

    private fun runtimePermission() {
        Dexter.withContext(context).withPermissions(
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ).withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
            override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport) {
                if (isAdded) { // Check if the fragment is added before calling displayFiles()
                    displayFiles()
                }
            }

            override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                list: MutableList<com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest>?,
                permissionToken: PermissionToken?,
            ) {
                permissionToken?.continuePermissionRequest()
            }
        }).check();
    }

    private fun findFile(file: File?): ArrayList<File> {

        val arrayList: ArrayList<File> = ArrayList()
        val files = file!!.listFiles()

        for (singleFile in files!!) {
            if (singleFile.isDirectory && !singleFile.isHidden) {
                arrayList.add(singleFile)
            }
        }
        return arrayList
    }

    private fun displayFiles() {
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        recycler.layoutManager = layoutManager
        fileList = ArrayList()
        fileList.addAll(findFile(storage))
        fileAdapter = FileAdapter(requireContext(), fileList, this)
        recycler.adapter = fileAdapter
    }

    override fun onFileClicked(file: File) {
        if (file.isDirectory) {
            val bundle: Bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("path", file.absolutePath)

            val internalFragment: InternalFragment = InternalFragment()
            internalFragment.arguments = bundle
            fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, internalFragment)
                ?.addToBackStack(null)?.commit();
        }
    }

    override fun onFileLongClicked(file: File) {
    }
}
```